# Is it possible to shut down an Ipod nano 6th generation?

Tags: ipod-nano, shutdown

If yes, how?

If no, why such a decision?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4354):

> If the iPod nano is paused, and you
>   press the Sleep/Wake button to turn
>   off the screen, the following behavior
>   will take place:
>
> - For 36 hours after pressing the Sleep/Wake button and turning off the
>     screen, iPod nano is in Standby, and
>     will quickly wake up when you press
>     the Sleep/Wake button again.
> - After 36 hours in Standby with no activity, iPod nano will shut down
>     automatically. Pressing the Sleep/Wake
>     button after iPod nano is shut down
>     will turn on iPod nano, and boot to
>     the main Home screen.
>     (Your iPod nano is considered paused if there is no music or FM radio playback, or an active pedometer session.)

Additional Information

- A fully charged iPod nano provides up to 24 hours of music playback time.

Answer (score 0):

Press all together in this order -Vol button, then Sleep button, then +Vol button and then hold (so your fingers should not let go of the -Vol when you press the Sleep button) until diagnostics screen, you'll see a teletype sorta menu select standby with the sleep button it will put the nano it sleep but wake up reset